# How to have INDEX/MATCH (or similar) function not repeat a match if there are duplicate values in the reference cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have used an =ArrayFormula(Large function to list my data and am trying to match each result with its corresponding title in the same row of the data set. Currently I am using =Index(reference,MATCH(search_key,range,0)) but if my search_key value in my list is the same as the another value, it just repeats the same title. I would like it to treat each one as a unique value and if the INDEX/MATCH has already retrieved a certain title that it would not duplicate it and go to the next match.

Comment: Bit hard to follow. Perhaps would benefit from a mockup   of some sample data and what should and should not happen.  You also didn't provide formulas so hard to know what we'd change.  Match shouldn't be looking for multiple results.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please edit your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider following Blind Spots' advice and share a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.